# Document-term matrix to a list of matrices R

Tags: r, matrix, tm, topic-modeling

I have a document-term matrix dtm, for example:

```
    dtm
    <<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 50, terms: 50)>>
    Non-/sparse entries: 220/2497
    Sparsity           : 100%
    Maximal term length: 7
    Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Now I want transfer it into a list of matrices, each represents a document. This is to fulfill the formal requirement of the package STM:

```
    [[1]]
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]  23   33   42   117
    [2,]   2    1    3     1

    [[2]]
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
    [1,]   2   19   93   168
    [2,]   2    2    1     1
```

I am thinking of finding all the non-zero entries from dtm and generate them into matrices, each row at a time, so:

```
    mat = matrix()
    dtm.to.mat = function(x){
        mat[1,] = x[x != 0]
        mat[2,] = colnames(x[x != 0])
        return(mat)
    }
    matrix = list(apply(dtm, 1, dtm.to.mat))
```

However,

```
     x[x != 0]
```

just won't work. The error says:

```
    $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I was wondering why this is the case. If I change x to matrix beforehand, it won't give me this error. However, I actually have a dtm of approximately 2,500,000 lines. I fear this will be very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Me again!

I wouldn't use a dtm as the input for the `stm` package unless your data is particularly strange. Use the function `stm::textProcessor`. You can specify the documents to be raw (unprocessed) text from an any length character vector. You can also specify the metadata as you wish:

Suppose you have a dataframe `df` with a column called `df$documents` which is your raw text and `df$meta` which is your covariate:

```
processed <- textProcessor(df$documents, metadata = df$meta, lowercase = TRUE,
  removestopwords = TRUE, removenumbers = TRUE, removepunctuation = TRUE,
  stem = TRUE, wordLengths = c(3, Inf))

stm_50 <- stm(documents = processed$documents, vocab = processed$vocab,
  K = 50, prevalence = ~ meta, init.type = "Spectral", seed = 57468)
```

This will run a 50 topic STM.

`textProcessor` will deal with empty documents and their associated metadata.

**Edit:** `stm::textProcessor` is technically just a wrapper for the `tm` package. But it is designed to remove problem documents, while dealing with their associated covariates.

Also the metadata argument can take a dataframe if you have multiple covariates. In that case you would also need to modify the prevalence argument in the second equation.

Comment: Hi Jamie! Thank you very much. The reason why I used dtm input is that I am dealing with Chinese texts. The textProcessor's processed$vocab gave me only garbles. I don't see an encoding parameter in the function though, and the "language =" parameter does not work, either.

Answer (score 1):

If you have something tricky like this I'd switch over to the `quanteda` package as it has nice converters to `stm`.  If you want to stick with `tm` have you tried using `stm::convertCorpus` to change the object into the list structure `stm` needs?